# If a DAG in airflow having 10 tasks and it fails in 5th task, how to make sure it starts from middle 5th task when the dag is triggered again?

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm setting up 10 tasks in a DAG in airflow, it is scheduled to run every 30 minutes, all tasks are supposed to run in a flow from 1>>2>>3>>4>>5>> upto 10th, supposed the 5th task fails how to make sure that next time the dag triggers, it starts from 5th task and not from 1st?

I expect it should start from 5th.

Comment: **[1]** Ideally failure of a single task should NOT require re-run of entire DAG, rather that task alone should be [retried](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/models/baseoperator.py#L86). That's the idea behind workflow **[2]** I believe this convoluted requirement hints that the design that you are trying to achieve is incorrect. **[3]** Even so, if you must have this functionality at any cost, you can try to build it yourself within Airflow by taking clues from [this](https://medium.com/@plieningerweb/use-apache-airflow-to-run-task-exactly-once-6fb70ca5e7ec)

Comment: If I put upto 3 retries on the 5th task and it still fails then it will stop right the dag run will be marked as failed. Now I want when I trigger the DAG again it starts from 3rd.

Comment: **[4]** an approach that i can think of is to skip (`ShortCircuitOperator` / `BranchPythonOperator` / `AirflowSkipException`) your first 4 tasks in case of re-run of DAG by determining the state of 5th task in the last run. For that, you'll have to query Airflow's meta-db for [task-state](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/bin/cli.py#L602)